# pv: -s: integer argument expected

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I have a script in which I am running this command:

```
pv -s `du -sb file1.data | awk '{s += $1} END {print s}'`
```

And it gives below error:

```
pv: -s: integer argument expected
```

So when I ran this command `du -sb file1.data | awk '{s += $1} END {print s}'`, it looks like output coming as:

```
1.03131e+10
```

So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: This depends (at least) on your version of awk and on which system you are on. Try using `printf` instead of `s +=`, you can also modify the output way easier. But allow me one question: why? What do you use this statement for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just format it using printf:

```
du -sb file1.data | awk '{s += $1} END {printf "%d\n", s}'
```

Or maybe you need `%ld` for really huge numbers:

```
du -sb file1.data | awk '{s += $1} END {printf "%ld\n", s}'
```

And if that fails (like I tested on FreeBSD with numbers like 1e32), then try this:

```
du -sb file1.data | python -c $'import sys\nt=0\nfor line in sys.stdin:\n    t += int(line.split()[0])\nprint(t)'
```